# Artifactory - Unable to add LDAP settings using either YAML config or API

Tags: jfrog-container-registry

**Using YAML**: I am trying to use the YAML configuration to add LDAP setting for Artifactory JCR. Tried using the helm chart version `107.63.7` (App ver.`7.63.7`) based on the following suggestion "Alternatively, from Artifactory version 7.63 and forward, you can use the Access Configuration Bootstrap YAML to set up authentication provider configuration" from [this](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/global-configuration-descriptor) page. Checking the `upstream` helm chart, I could not find any mention of `access.security.bootstrap.yml`. This made me think whether the helm chart is up-to-date with the latest changes. I instead thought of appending the LDAP settings block to the following secret and although I could see the `copy-system-configurations` container copying the stuff to `/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc/access/access.config.patch.yml` but LDAP didn't work. This is one issue.

```
stringData:
  access.config.patch.yml: |
    security:
      tls: false
      ldapSettings:
      ...
      ...
```

**Using API**: Since above didn't work, I reverted to version `7.59.11` after I came across [this](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/add-ldap-settings) link and tried the POST command but that always keep throwing the same error.

```
$ curl -s -u admin:cmVm...redacted...MjIz -X POST https://jcr.my.domain.com/access/api/v1/ldap/settings -H "Content-Type: application/json" -T ldap.json
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"HTTP 401 Unauthorized","detail":"Request has failed. Due to incorrect username/password or locked user."}]}
```

Also tried this form but same result:

```
$ curl -s -u admin:cmVm...redacted...MjIz -X POST https://jcr.my.domain.com/access/api/v1/ldap/settings -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @ldap.json
```

Few things I would like to mention:

- I am using `Identity Token` for admin user
- Property `Lock User After Exceeding Max Failed Login Attempts` is disabled.

I would preferably like to use the method that the docs suggest for the latest version i.e., using the `access.security.bootstrap.yml` instead of running the API command but any help will be appreciated. Even better if I get to know how to get both the methods working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Identity Token`, this is the syntax that finally worked for me:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer xyZd...SUpx" "https://<my-artifactory>/access/api/v1/ldap/settings" -d @ldap.json -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Answer (score 1):

As it was handy, I quickly tested the REST API and it is working perfectly fine.
Logged in as Admin > Right side top corner > Edit profile > Passed the password > Create Identity Token

Now ran the below command with the above token

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXX" "http://myartifactory.jfrog.io/access/api/v1/ldap/settings" -t editldap.json
```

where my editldap.son as below.

```
{
    "key": "ldap1",
    "enabled": true,
    "ldap_url": "ldap://somehost",
    "user_dn_pattern": "uid={0}",
    "search": {
      "search_filter": null,
      "search_base": null,
      "search_sub_tree": false,
      "manager_dn": null,
      "manager_password": null
    },
    "auto_create_user": true,
    "email_attribute": "email",
    "ldap_poisoning_protection": false,
    "allow_user_to_access_profile": false,
    "paging_support_enabled": true
}
```

I think the way you are passing is wrong. Give a try with this snippet.

Comment: +1. Thanks. I did try using the `Authorization Bearer` syntax as well earlier but that didn't work for me because I was using incorrect path in the URL. I again tried with the correct path and that didn't work either using `-t` option that you suggested. However, I was able to retrieve existing LDAP settings using above command without the `-t` option.